# flask db.create_all() not alter table

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

### model

```py
class Member(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Member'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    m_grouppermission_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('GroupPermission.id'), nullable=True)
```

### command

> db.create_all()

create_all command is only db create?

Foreign keys are not currently updated.

How to alter table?

Comment: Have a look at [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: can you share the code where you initialise app and db

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the db first db.drop_all() and then run db.create_all()